# How to add text to anchor with image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an image link that I want to turn into image and text link.

Having this:

```
<a href="http://example.com/" class="link">  
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/s3zp1u2.jpg" /></a>
```

I want to get this (notice 'Cat' text):

```
<a href="http://example.com/" class="link">  
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/s3zp1u2.jpg" />Cat</a>
```

My [code](http://jsfiddle.net/0g8yuq0o/) adds the text but removes the image:

```
$(function(){
    $('.link').text('Cat');
});
```

Comment: try this var linkImage = $('.link').html();    
    $('.link').html(linkImage + 'Cat');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest would be to add an extra span

```
<a href="http://example.com/" class="link">  
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/s3zp1u2.jpg" />
  <span></span>
</a>
```

js

```
$(function(){
    $('.link span').text('Cat');
});
```

AN alternative is to use `append()`

Comment: Using span is an interesting idea. Should be also easier to remove text from such link as well?

Comment: yes, easier to remove than a text node, just add empty string

Answer (score 1):

Use [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) instead of `text`.

```
$(function(){
    $('.link').append('Cat');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0g8yuq0o/1/

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
$(function(){
    $('.link').append('Cat');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To what have already been suggested, I can only add a pure Javascript solution:

```
<a href="http://example.com/" class="link">  
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/s3zp1u2.jpg" />
  <span id="cat-001-text">Cat</span>
</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("cat-001-text").innerHTML = "dog";
</script>
```

Comment: I need to dynamically add / remove text from image anchors.